# Torus interior homeomorphic to torus exterior

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $T^2 \subset \mathbb{R^3}$, then $X_i$ be its interior and $X_e$ its exterior. By computing homotopy groups of $X_i \cup T^2$ and $X_e \cup T^2$ and corresponding isomorphisms between, one could show with Whitehead's theorem that $X_i$ is homotopy equivalent to $X_e$.

But how could I show that $X_e$ is homeomorphic to $X_i$?

Comment: This is not really true. It is true if you embed the torus in $S^3$, but in $\mathbb R^3$ the exterior is missing a point.

Comment: Is the exterior of $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R^3}$ missing also a point as compared to the interior of $S^2$?

Comment: Sure. The exterior of $S^2$ has the homotopy type of $S^2$ while the interior is contractible, for example. It follows that they do not have the same homotpy type, let alone are they homeomorphic.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Thank you, I think you can add it as an answer.

Comment: Notice that I did not *prove* that the two sets are not homeomorphic :-)

Comment: In any case, it might be a good idea if you were more explicit about how you plan to use Whitehead's theorem to show the two spaces have the same homotopy type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I think of it. The one point compactification of $\mathbb R^3$ is $S^3$. If you dig out a standard ball from $S^3$ it's believable that the complement is a ball, but you can also prove this directly using stereographic projection. If you remove a standard ball, the complement is a union of rays emanating from a sphere out to infinity. That is, it is a cone on a sphere, which is a ball.

So now I have a $S^3$ written as the union of $2$ balls, one of which contains $\infty$. Drill a straight hole through the center of the bounded ball. This has the effect of creating a bounded solid torus. Now what happens to the unbounded ball is that a solid tube gets added to it along its boundary. Abstractly, if you add a solid tube to a $3$-ball to get an orientable $3$-manifold, the result is a solid torus.